# segmentation fault when adding array to a node n-ary tree

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

I'm trying to create an N-ary tree where I have a char array ex: {A,B,C,D} to insert to a tree.

I set the root to be "/"

if the command is mkdir /A/B/C => create node A at root, then B at A and C at B. if the command is mkdir B/C/D =>create node D inside C, etc... I simplified the code below so hopefully, there won't be any typo here. Anyway, upon debugging with gdb, it looks like the upon reaching search function will give me a segmentation fault, I made the code below, I'm really sure the insert function will have the same error as well but I haven't been able to test it out yet.

head.c

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define len 128
#define num 128

typedef struct tree{
    char name;
    char type;
    struct node *child, *sibbling, *parentNode;

}node;
char  *baseName[64];
node *root, *cwd;
```

tree.c

```
node *createNode(node * newNode, char ch, char ty){

            node *curNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            curNode->name = ch;
            curNode->type = ty;
            curNode->parentNode = newNode;
            curNode->sibbling = curNode->child=NULL;
            return curNode;

        }


node * insertNode(node *parent, char name, char type){

                if(parent->child == NULL){
                    parent->child=parent;
                    createNode(parent->child,name,type);
                }

                else{
                    parent->sibbling = parent;
                    createNode(parent->sibbling,name,type);

                }
            }

node *searchNode(node *curNode, char name){

    if(curNode->name ==name){  <------------error here
            return curNode;
    }

    if(name != curNode->name && curNode->sibbling != '\0'){
         searchNode(curNode->sibbling, name);
    }

    if(name != curNode->name && curNode->child != '\0'){
         searchNode(curNode->sibbling, name);
                }
    return 0;       
}


void mkDir(){
    int index = 0;
    int flag =0;
    int baseFlag=0;

    node *pwd = root;

          ///// insert
           while(dirName[index] !='\0'){
              if(searchNode(root,dirName[index]) != NULL){ <-- error in this searchNode function //no node exist
                       // insertNode(pwd,"A","D"); <---this probably error too
                        printf("found A");
                 }

                   else{
                      //node exist
                      cwd = searchNode(root,dirName[index]);
                      insertNode(cwd,dirName[index],"D");

                  }
               index++;
               }  
    }



    memset(dirName,'\0',sizeof(dirName));



                        }
```

Comment: You wrote: _"I simplified the code below so hopefully, there won't be any typo here"_. Why didn't you check that this simplified code compiles and actually reproduces the problem? Please read this: [mcve]

Comment: `curNode->sibbling != '\0'){`  You are confusing NULL and 0 here.

Comment: `typedef struct tree{` --> `typedef struct node{`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are passing in a null node reference to the `searchNode` function, hence when you try to access the property `name` you are getting a segfault.

I would recommend testing for and handling for null references in your code.

Answer (score 0):

function `createNode` return type is `node*`.In function `insertNode` you must store the `address` of `new node` in some other variable of type `node*`.

```
              node *r
              r=createNode(parent->child,name,type);
              ....
              ...
```

In the function `searchNode` you must check

```
   if(curnode!=NULL)  {
       if(curNode->name ==name){
        return curNode;
  }
 }
```

In the last line you are returning 0 but return type is `node*`

return either `NULL` or `(node*)0`.